# Probability of not detecting fire if two of the sensors don't work well

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

I am trying to solve the following problem of probability:

"In a certain factory, there is an alarm system composed of 5 sensors that work independently to detect fire. The probability that a sensor works well, that is, warns people when there's fire is $0.8$. If two of the sensors don't work well, which is the probabilty of not detecting the fire?".

I have thought of Bayes $p(A|B)$ where A="Not detecting fire" and B="2 sensors don't work well". In this way, I have computed the probability as:

$$\frac{1*0.2^5}{\binom{5}{2}0.2^2*0.8^3}$$.
However, the result of this isn't the one that appears in the solutions of the textbook because the solution should be $0.008$. Any help to approach the problem? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't clear.  If a sensor isn't working well, is it useless?  And if a sensor is working well, is it flawless?  And, when you say that "two of the sensors don't work well" do you mean *at least* two or *exactly* two?

Comment: Evidently, when a sensor doesn't work there is a 100% chance that it fails to detect a fire. The three remaining sensors detect a fire with probability $p$, independently of the others so the probability that all three will fail to detect is $(1-p)^3$.

Comment: This also depends on the probability of having a fire? The probability of (not) detecting fire when having fire is likely different from the probability of (not) detecting fire when there's no fire.

Comment: Yeah, the correct answer to the best-guessed interpretation of the problem is about is $0.001218$, as K.Jiang says in their answer. However, you can get $0.008$ if the problem is interpreted differently. (IMHO nobody _should_ interpret is like that, but there we go!) So, if the sensors are A, B, C, D and E, and _we know_ that A and B are faulty, what is the probability of not detecting the fire? It is $0.2^3=0.008$, of course, because this is just the probability that all three of C, D, E will also be faulty.

Answer (score 2):

We will assume that "sensor works" is synonymous to "detects fire". The question then becomes "given that at least two sensors don't work, what is the probability that none of the sensors work?".

The probability that two of the sensors don't work can be found via complementary counting by subtracting from unity the probability that all the sensors work and the probability that only one of the sensors doesn't work: $1 - (0.8)^5 - 5 (0.2) (0.8)^4$. The probability that *none* of the sensors work (leaving the fire undetected) is $(0.2)^5$. The desired conditional probability is

$$\frac{(0.2)^5}{1 - (0.8)^5 - 5 (0.2) (0.8)^4} \approx \boxed{0.001218}$$

**EDIT**: Clarification on why $0.008$ is a *bad* answer.

As @John Douma mentioned in the comments, the textbook answer was probably found by taking $(0.2)^3$. However, as @Stinking Bishop has pointed out, this assumes that we know that *two specific* alarms don't work. That is *not* the same question as what was posed, which is that given that *some* pair of alarms don't work, what is the probability that the fire is not detected.

Comment: it is should be assumed that exactly two sensors don't work well, as your answer doesn't match with the TB. Also, even the OP assumed it _exactly_ 2.

Comment: @DS If *exactly* two sensors don't work well, then the question is trivial - three of the sensors work, so the fire will always be detected.

Comment: but the OP asks why their answer doesn't come out be $0.008$, not another interpretation of the problem. It would be worth pointing out that they've not used $P(A|B)$ properly (as I'm doing in my answer,  which will be posted in a few mins)

Comment: @DS So the answer should really be "the problem is badly posed, throw the textbook in the bin!", at least it looks like that to me!

Comment: @StinkingBishop there are a lot of elementary textbooks which often use ambiguous exercises, and the meaning has to be derived from the answers.

Comment: @DS I know ... quite infuriating. Especially if they later give you a problem from that book on a test. If you have a grain of perfectionism in your personality, this encourages you to learn the answers from the book by rote! Which is exactly the opposite of what maths is about. (Or, alternatively, you get convinced that maths is a random set of rules to remember, which is quite off-putting.) But I digress...

Answer (score 1):

Well, as John Douma pointed out in the answer, the probability is $(1-p)^3 = 0.008$. This is because the probability of a sensor failing is $1-p = 1-0.8 = 0.2$. Since you have 3 sensors (the other two are already faulty), we get $0.2^3 = 0.008$. 
To get the same answer using $P(A|B)$, you need to use the formula properly
$$P(A|B) = {P(A \cap B)\over P(B)} = {n(A \cap B)\over n(B)}$$
$n(A \cap B)$ is just the number of ways in which $2$ are permanently faulty and the remaining fail. That is $\binom{5}{2}(0.2)^5$. $n(B)$ is the number of ways you can choose which ones fail, so that is $\binom 52(0.2)^2$. Now apply the formula:
$$P(A|B) = {\binom{5}{2}(0.2)^5\over \binom 52(0.2)^2} = 0.008$$
You've made two errors: You've considered the probability of all $5$ faulting in the numerator, but you are already given $2$ of them are faulty, so you should just choose the faulty ones (because you need to differentiate between which ones were already faulty and which faulted during the fire, otherwise you're undercounting). In the denominator, $B$ is just $2$ don't work well (so again, just choose them and make them faulty), you are not required to make the others error-free. (If you make the others error-free, $A$ and $B$ become disjoint).

Comment: I've assumed exactly two sensors fail here